# Folder/FileName Path Save?

Tags: asp-classic, path

I wanted to do when saving pdf folder/FileName.pdf want to save the form. The following code saves only the FileName pdf

```
Case "new"
on error resume next

Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")

Upload.SetMaxSize 1000000, True

Upload.Codepage = 1254

Upload.OverwriteFiles = False

Upload.Save

Set File1 = Upload.Files("pdf")

Path = server.mappath("../PDF-N/")

if File1.Ext = ".pdf" or File1.Ext=".pdf" or File1.Ext=".PDF" then

File1.SaveAs Path & "\"& File1.FileName

pdf = File1.FileName

end if

metin = tirnak(Upload.form("metin"))

sql= "Insert into tblHaber(metin,pdf) values('" & metin & "', '"& pdf & "')"
conn.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the line:-

```
on error resume next
```

currently something bad can be happening but you wouldn't be informed.  Generally `On Error Resume Next` is a bad thing to have in a body of code.

This isn't going to solve your problem but it may provide some insight as to what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem    

pdf = File1.filename >  pdf = "PDF-N" & "\"& File1.FileName